# Mercurial: Forget files of a certain extension

Tags: mercurial, design-patterns

How do I remove all files from a mercurial repository having the `.class` extension?

This use of patterns does not work:

```
PS> hg forget -I **.class
abort: no files specified
```

However, this use of patterns lists all the files I would like to forget:

```
PS> hg status -A -I **.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\DiscreteDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\ExponentialDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\GaussianDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\GaussianMixtureDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\MultiGaussianDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\MultiRandomDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\PoissonDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\RandomDistribution.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\distributions\SimpleMatrix.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\Centroid.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\CentroidFactory.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\CentroidObservationInteger.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\CentroidObservationReal.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\CentroidObservationVector.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\ForwardBackwardCalculator$Computation.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\ForwardBackwardCalculator.class
C be\ac\ulg\montefiore\run\jahmm\ForwardBackwardScaledCalculator.class
```

What am I not understanding about the way forget treats patterns?  I am using Mercurial version 2.0.

Comment: Try `hg reverse` with those files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're just missing a little something in your command :

```
 hg forget -I **.class .
```

Note the added `.` at the end which tells Mercurial in which directory to look.

It's working with `status`, because `status` look in every directory by default if nothing is specified. For the `forget` command you must specify the files / directory explicitly

Comment: {*.class,*.etc} It is also true ;)